# Creating new Thread to update GUI

Tags: android

Im trying to do this silly "game" where I have a relative layout and classes that extend from View. I create the Views and want to add them onto the Relative layout using a Thread. So far so good. I had it working just fine with little object views scrolling down the relative layout. I then added two more screens for options and only after those screens I wanted to show the Activity with the scrolling views. The problem is that it stop working with the following error:

08-03 20:13:48.140: E/AndroidRuntime(5152): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I can´t understand this error...

Here is the sample code for the thread that starts and the function that updates the UI:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    context = this.getApplicationContext();

    /*load all bitmaps*/
    loadBitmaps();

    /*get all the activities components*/
    gameCanvasRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.gameCanvasRL);
    playerScoreTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playerPoints);

    /*GameManager instance*/
    manager = GameManager.getInstance();

    /*Start Threads*/
    startAllThreads();
}

private void startAllThreads() {
    refreshCanvasHandler = new Handler();
    spawnHandler = new Handler();

    refreshCanvasThread = new Thread(new RefreshCanvasTask());
    spawnTask = new Thread(new spawnTask());

    refreshCanvasThread.start();
    spawnTask.start();
}

class RefreshCanvasTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            refreshCanvasHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    refreshCanvas();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

private void refreshCanvas() {
        int germSize;

```
    /*Move all germs*/
    manager.moveGerms();
    germSize = manager.getGerms().size();

    if(gameCanvasRL.getChildCount() > 0)
        gameCanvasRL.removeAllViews();

    for(int i = 0; i < germSize; i++) {
        gameCanvasRL.addView(manager.getGerms().get(i));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means you're trying to add a view that is already added to another view.  A view may only have 1 parent, so the second add throws an exception.  You need to remove it from the original parent before adding it to the new one.

Comment: how do u recommend doing that? and where? the thing is that it works fine when, in the manifest, I have this activity as the main one. If I start this activity with the Intent it stops working =/